# <dirent.h> in Visual Studio 2010 or 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I want to use `#include <dirent.h>` in my code but this error happens:

> Cannot open include file: 'dirent.h': No such file or directory

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It is too heavily tied to *nix.  On Windows use _findfirst/_findnext to iterate directories, `#include <io.h>`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Because this header file doesn't come with MSVC. Hence it cannot find it!

It comes with **C POSIX library**.  The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h) says,

> dirent.h is known to be included in
>   the following compilers:
>
> - Turbo C++ (DOS)
> - GCC (Cross-platform)
> - MinGW (Microsoft Windows)
> - Borland C++ Builder (Microsoft Windows)
>
> Microsoft Visual C++ does not include
>   dirent.h

However, you can download [**free Windows implementation of dirent.h**](https://web.archive.org/web/20170428133315/http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php) which you can use with Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: How can I use it in visual studio ?

Comment: the latest version (april 2012) of dirent for windows has bugs, I am using first version (2006) now. 
Source of the first version: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/avro/trunk/lang/c/tests/msdirent.h

Comment: The link appears broken.

Comment: This is the GitHub repo linked from the original webpage: https://github.com/tronkko/dirent

Comment: Damn you Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

[This is another light-weight dirent.h implementation for Windows](http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.html). It is two files that you can just drop in as-is.

Currently, the best way of getting *full POSIX support* on Windows is probably [Cygwin or its friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385424/good-alternatives-to-cygwin-cygwin-doesnt-support-natively-support-win32-app).

There is [Windows Services for UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Services_for_UNIX) (SfU), but [according to some](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=47318) it was quite close to what Cygwin was in 2006. Seeing how Cygwin and some of its comrads are live and well and SfU did not see an update in over half a decade, I would choose the former any day of the week.

If you are interested in a blast from the past, checkout [this little nugget from 2006](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048.aspx) which is Microsoft's official *How to port from UNIX to Windows* website. It seems rather useless, but funny what Microsoft thought is "useful" in 2006.

Comment: In the code you recommend struct dirent does not define the content of directory entries. It's useless for most applications.

Comment: @Jay Good point. Also, things have changed since my last post. Nowadays, [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) seems to be the go-to solution. But after recent Microsoft announcements, we can assume that the new Windows will allow for even better integration (or so they promise... :/)