# Visual Studio /SUBSYSTEM:POSIX not appearing in 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, posix

I have installed visual studio 2008 Professional Edition and I am not able to set /SUBSYSTEM:POSIX option in one of the visual C++ projects. I also installed Visual Studio Debugger addin from SUA but still same. Please see attached screenshot for version information.

[image]

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's gone. However, Visual Studio does provide a bunch of header files to provide functionality that gets close (but not the same), such as [`direct.h`for directory operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as5kw0ze.aspx).

Currently, the best way of getting POSIX on Windows is probably [Cygwin or it's friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385424/good-alternatives-to-cygwin-cygwin-doesnt-support-natively-support-win32-app).

There is [Windows Services for UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Services_for_UNIX) (SfU), but [according to some](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=47318) it was quite close to what Cygwin was in 2006. Seeing how Cygwin and some of its comrads are live and well and SfU did not see an update in over half a decade, I would choose the former any day of the week.

If you are interested in a blast from the past, checkout [this little nugget from 2006](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048.aspx) which is Microsoft's official *How to port from UNIX to Windows* website. It seems rather useless, but funny what Microsoft thought is "useful" in 2006.