# Command Line terminal in windows

Tags: windows

I just started developing in windows and I don't really like using the "cmd" terminal. Is there any other alternative out there?

Comment: What kind of application are you developing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good alternative Windows console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440269/whats-a-good-alternative-windows-console)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use cmd, use Powershell.

Comment: Any authoritative reference for such strong a command?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something which is Windows-centered and is not `cmd.exe`, use [`PowerShell`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). If you're looking for a more "Linuxy" style, I prefer `Cygwin`, but there are [quite a few alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385424/good-alternatives-to-cygwin-cygwin-doesnt-support-natively-support-win32-app).