# Windows fnmatch substitute

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code in Linux that looks for files that matches the given wildcard:

```
    std::vector<std::string> listFilenamesInPath(std::string wildcard = "*", std::string directory = "./")
    {
        std::vector<std::string> result;
        DIR* dirp = opendir(directory.c_str());

        if (dirp)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                struct dirent* de = readdir(dirp);

                if (de == NULL)
                    break;

                if (fnmatch(wildcard.c_str(), de->d_name, 0))
                    continue;
                else
                    result.push_back (std::string(de->d_name));
            }

            closedir(dirp);
        }

        std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());

        return result;
    }
```

I´m porting this code to Windows and found out that `fnmatch` is not available  (`dirent` is also not available, but I could find one according to the following [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530933/dirent-h-in-visual-studio-2010-or-2008).

Is there a fnmatch substitute function that does exactly the same thing ?

How can I make this code compile and run in a VS2012 without breaking up my logic ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx The family of ``FindFirstFile(),FindNextFile()...`` functions might be what you are looking for.

Comment: If boost is an option it offers functions like this that work on Linux and Windows. boost::filesystem , boost::path etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like PathMatchSpec is your guy.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for SergeyA for the help. Here is my final solution in case someone needs in future...

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "dirent.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "shlwapi.h"
#else
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>
#endif
    std::vector<std::string> listFilenamesInPath(std::string wildcard = "*", std::string directory = "./")
    {
        std::vector<std::string> result;

        DIR* dirp = opendir(directory.c_str());

        if (dirp)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                struct dirent* de = readdir(dirp);

                if (de == NULL)
                    break;

#ifdef _WIN32
            wchar_t wname[1024];
            wchar_t wmask[1024];

            size_t outsize;
            mbstowcs_s(&outsize, wname, de->d_name, strlen(de->d_name) + 1);
            mbstowcs_s(&outsize, wmask, wildcard.c_str(), strlen(wildcard.c_str()) + 1);

            if (PathMatchSpecW(wname, wmask))
                result.push_back (std::string(de->d_name));
            else
                continue;
#else
                if (fnmatch(wildcard.c_str(), de->d_name, 0))
                    continue;
                else
                    result.push_back (std::string(de->d_name));
#endif
            }

            closedir(dirp);
        }

        std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());

        return result;
    }
```

Please comment if something can be improved...