# Cannot find seekdir() in dirent.h for Windows (C++)

Tags: c++, c, windows, dirent.h

I'm Actually working on a project and I have to browse directories and for this i'm using dirent.h library since I dont want to use Boost just for that.
Hence I found this post [<dirent.h> in visual studio 2010 or 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530933/dirent-h-in-visual-studio-2010-or-2008) which lead to here http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php where I downloaded and installed dirent.h.
So dirent.h is installed and I have no problem using basic functions like opendir, readdir but when  I wanted to use seekdir() function, it seems that it does not exist in the library so I went in dirent.h to verify my hypothesis and (Thanks Ctrl+F) seekdir is indeed missing.
Did I miss something or do I have to find a trick to get this function ...?
Thanking you.

Comment: you want to learn the difference between *header files* and *libraries*. Downloading the header will not suffice.

Comment: Can you explain more please? I mean I followed the little tutorial and I could use function from dirent.h and those functions actually work :/

Comment: It is header only library, so nothing but an .h file is needed. It seems `seekdir` is simply not implemented by the author.

Comment: @Ari0nhh I was looking for other implementation  too and it seems that seekdir is just not implemented :/

Comment: Windows POSIX support is hit and miss. [Give this a try instead.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry I forgot to mention that I wanted to avoid "Windows version" ( Of course it would be easier since I'm on VS but  I was like "oh $*ù^$ this I want to use linux things" ( I learnt C and C++ programming  on  Linux platform :p ). But thank you anyway! :)

Comment: If your compiler is up to date, you may be able to turn on C++17's file system support by setting a compiler option to get experimental, pre standardization libraries. other than that, it's a portability library like the already-rejected boost.

Comment: @user4581301 Ok i'll give a try! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The only functions available in that header are:

```
DIR *opendir (const char *dirname);
struct dirent *readdir (DIR *dirp);
int closedir (DIR *dirp);
void rewinddir (DIR* dirp);
```

There is no trick to get the functionality you need. You simply need to find another library for this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you cant locate the header file `dirent.h`  then try using `WIN32_FIND_DATA` , `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()` as an alternative. Two different codes are submitted. One for Visual Studio 6.o and another for Visual Studio 2013 which requires the use of wide characters.

Code for Visual studio 6.0:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void listdirandfiles(string dir){
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA data;

    hFind = FindFirstFileA(dir.c_str(), &data);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            printf("%s\n", data.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

        string dir = "c:\\*.*";
        cout<<"\nListing directories or files..\n\n";
        listdirandfiles(dir);

        cout<<"\nPress ANY key to close.\n\n";
        cin.ignore(); cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

code for Visual Studio 2013 :

```
// visual studio 2013
// listdirConsoleApplication15.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


wchar_t *convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
{
    wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
}

void listdirandfiles(char *wstr){
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    hFind = FindFirstFile(convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(wstr), &FindFileData);

    do{
        _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), FindFileData.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));

    FindClose(hFind);

}

int main( )
{

    char *wstr = "c:\\*.*";

    cout << "\nListing directories or files..\n\n";

    listdirandfiles(wstr);

    cout << "\nPress ANY key to close.\n\n";
    cin.ignore(); cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: WRT "which requires the use of wide characters[,]" Windows typically provides two functions, one with a 'W' suffix for wide characters and one with an 'A' suffix for good ol' 8 bit ANSI.By default, a given function will be defined to point at the 'W' version. Eg.  a `FindFirstFile` is defined to `FindFirstFileW`. `FindFirstFileA` can be called directly or somewhere out there there will be a compiler option to globally redirect from the 'W's to the 'A's. Danged if I can remember the option, though.