# unable to list directory content for all file types in C:\ using C program

Tags: c, enumeration, directory-listing

This is a C snippet I'm looking at

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <types.h>

static void list_dir(const char *path)
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n",entry->d_name);
    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

Can't understand out of the many complicated concepts, which logic to follow for listing out directory content of any desired directory (C:\ OR D:\ whatever) and NOT current directory.

If I could be clarified as to what is missed in the code. Want the logic, the methodology so I could then code as I go.

Comment: What happens when you pass `"c:\\"` to the function? What are the "many complicated concepts"?

Comment: Where is the code that calls this function?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking in your question. You should edit it so that it has definitive question (e.g. at least one sentence that naturally ends with a question mark). As is your question will likely receive votes to close for being too broad.

Comment: Look at `FindFirst(), FindNext()` apis.

Comment: @Toby it isn't unclear what he is asking: he is asking how to get `opendir()` to open an arbitrary directory rather than the current one. What we are lacking is an MCVE because the problem is clearly not in this code.

Comment: You need to show how you are constructing the parameter to `list_dir` because, unless `opendir` is broken on Windows, it should open the directory you supply in the parameter.

Comment: Since you are on Windows, you might want to check out this answer that uses native Windows functions http://stackoverflow.com/a/884888/169346

Comment: `opendir()` and the other functions from `dirent.h` are part of POSIX, so unless you are using SUA on pre-window 8 OS or something similar, POSIX functions will not work directly on Windows AFAIK (depending on your compiler, eg MSVS does not have it IIRC), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530933/dirent-h-in-visual-studio-2010-or-2008

Comment: @JeremyP, the _problem_ is clear, the asker is attempting to use a function intended for linux use on a windows system (apparently, we don't actually have the windows info other than the presence of windows path). But the _question_ is not clear "Can't understand out of the many complicated concepts, which logic to follow for listing out directory content of any desired directory (C:\ OR D:\ whatever) and NOT current directory. If I could be clarified as to what is missed in the code. Want the logic, the methodology so I could then code as I go." is not a question.

Comment: @Toby "Want the logic, the methodology so I could then code as I go" means that I want to understand how the methodology of invoking the core works and how the result is achieved. That was what I intended to convey, shall I explain my problem more now?

Comment: @rhym1n That would be a good edit :)