# im trying to run this code on visual studio, but cannot because of dirent.h . is there any other ways to do the same thing but still on visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dirent.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;

bool has_suffix(const string& s, const string& suffix)
{
    return (s.size() >= suffix.size()) && equal(suffix.rbegin(), suffix.rend(), s.rbegin());    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "Directory name: ";
    string path;
    getline(cin, path);

    DIR *dir = opendir(path.c_str());
    if(!dir)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    dirent *entry;
    while((entry = readdir(dir))!=null) 
    {
        if(has_suffix(entry->d_name, ".txt"))
        {
            cout << entry->d_name << endl;
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

this code is basically listing out all files that have the same extension(.txt) in a directory. so im trying to do this but on visual studio instead of using any other IDE.

is there another way to do this? like replacing dirent.h with something else. im trying to avoid importing library since if i were to use the same code on other pc, i afraid later it will give an error also. im trying to find any function that can do the same function as dirent. but so far i dont find it yet, or maybe i didnt noticed/understand it.

btw, im using windows

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? The most recent should have support for C++'s new [`<filesystem>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) which  has all sorts of groovy, cross platform tools that can help make this job easier.

Comment: It occurs I should also drop a suggestion in case you are not using an up-to-date version of Visual Studio: Read up on [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) and [`FindFirstFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfileexa) and pick the one that best fits your needs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<dirent.h> in visual studio 2010 or 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530933/dirent-h-in-visual-studio-2010-or-2008)

Comment: im using visualstudio2012

Comment: The link from @acraig5075 should also work in 2012. I still suggest looking at `the FindFirstFile` win32 API calls though. They do the `if(has_suffix(entry->d_name, ".txt"))` for you.

Comment: @SectumSempra Makes no difference.

Comment: okay2. i will go through each of them and see which one is best suited for my case. hehe

Comment: thank you all. im using the findfirstfile ways.